# Create .NET 2.0 Standalone WebService

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-2.0

I have to create a Web Service running in a C# Console Application in a .NET 2.0 Environment. 
I can not use WCF or upgrade the target system to a recent .NET version.

I have googled a lot but did not find anything that fits.

Someone has a suggestion?

Comment: Ask whoever is insisting on no upgrades if they're truly happy for a solution to be built on top of a base that's been out of [mainstream support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/search?sort=pn&alpha=.net%20framework) for almost 4 years and only has a little over a year of extended support remaining.

Comment: Can you even get an operating system that doesn't at least have .net 3.5.1 installed? Surely that means the OS is beyond extended support.

Comment: Unfortunately the web service will be installed also on old legacy environment with Windows 2000 and .net 2.0. We are not allowed to update .net or upgrade the o/s

Answer (score 0):

This is an old example of how to host a webservice in a windows service.

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class Service : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public Service () {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

}

public partial class WindowsServiceToHostASMXWebService : ServiceBase
{
    public WindowsServiceToHostASMXWebService()
    {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            Uri address = new Uri("soap.tcp://localhost/TestService");
            SoapReceivers.Add(new EndpointReference(address), typeof(Service ));
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            SoapReceivers.Clear();
        }
        static void Main()
        {
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
            // Change the following line to match.
            ServicesToRun = new System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase[] { new WindowsServiceToHostASMXWebService() };
            System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
        }
    }
```

Comment: try to avoid posting link-only answers, as they are considered poor quality (as well as the link may break in future)

Comment: If you make that work for a console application it would be an actual answer to the question. Don't forget to explain that the OP needs the WSE3.0 download for this to fly.